# Vector of tuples (x1,y1), (x2,y2),... or separate vectors (x1,x2,...), (y1,y2,...)

Tags: c++, qt, plot, data-structures

I'm looking for a practical and "good" object-oriented-C++-Qt way to represent `data` in the form of tuples (xi,yi):

```
x  | y
=======
x1 | y1
x2 | y2
 . | .
xn | yn
```

which will be made available at certain points in my application by *reference*. This `data` will be plotted repeatedly in given time intervals during which other functions may access the `data` reference and modify it, causing the changes to appear in the next plotted "frame".

The plotting tool (`QCustomPlot`) demands the `x` and `y` columns as `QVector<double>`. In the early design stages I made something like (pseudo-code):

```
class TupleXY {
    double x;   // xi
    double y;   // yi
};
```

used in a `QVector<TupleXY> data;`.

After the need for the `x` and `y` columns/vectors arose **(*)**, when I decided to go for `QCustomPlot`, I introduced (version 1):

```
class DataXYv1 {
    QVector<TupleXY> data; //with direct access
    QVector<double> getX() const {
        QVector<double> result;
        result.reserve(data.size());
        foreach(TupleXY xy in data)
            result[i] = xy.x;
        return result;
    }
    QVector<double> getY() const {//analogous}
};
```

However, **isn't this a very inefficient way to prepare the data for plotting?** This has to be performed for every frame!

Naturally, I created a class (version 2):

```
class DataXYv2 {
    QVector<double> x;
    QVector<double> y;
    void addTuple(TupleXY xy) {x.append(xy.x); y.append(xy.y);}
    TupleXY& getTuple(int index) {
        if (index is valid)
            return TupleXY(x[index], y[index]) //these have to be references in order to workf or data manipulation...
        end
    }
    ...
};
```

which delivers the `x`- and `y`-vectors directly.

However, this design makes iterating through the vector of data points (xi,yi) more cumbersome, the pairs of (xi,yi) are mapped only via the position in the respective vectors, equal length of the vectors can't be easily assured and, since the data *has* to be available by reference, the correct mapping can't be guaranteed...

1) Is one of the above versions the preferred/more typical way of doing things? This seems such a trivial situation and yet I can't decide how one would create such a data structure...
2) How would you, for example, achieve the desired functionality (storing multiple (xi,yi) datapoints, providing direct reference access and the possibility to get x and y vectors)?

**(*)** I don't assume that adding the tuples point by point is efficient...

Comment: Do note that in `DataXYv2` `getTuple` returns a reference to a function local object and using that is undefined behavior.

Comment: If you store your `TupleXY` objects in a vector, you can access each point in constant time, I guess, by calling `m_tuples.at(i).x` and `m_tuples.at(i).y`, assuming that `m_tuples` is `std::vector<TupleXY>` and `0 <= i < m_tuples.size()`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, thank you. This would demand the `TupleXY` class to work with references. I could just `get` x and y of one tuple separately.
@vahancho I use `QVector`. However, getting access to the member fields is not the question but more the general design of the class if the data shall accessible (which greatly discourages the "two-vectors"-approach) and x-/y-vectors must be constructed...

Comment: Do you **need** an OO design or will fundamental data structures work here?

Comment: In the graphics world, fundamental drawing is by points or pixels.  Each point has a location.  The graphics API are usually written to either require a Point structure or passing the coordinates separately.  If you want efficiency, design your container around the API of the graphics package.  However, I recommend not using parallel array, or vectors, as they are more prone to maintenance issues versus a container of points.

Comment: Before optimizing, **Profile**.  Find out where in your program the most time is spent.  You may want to optimize at the design level.  For example, having the graphics package draw a line or polygon may be more efficient than your program drawing the individual points.  Most graphics packages are optimized for speed.

Comment: Conceptually, at a low level, you are passing two integers to a function.  This is usually performed using registers; can't optimize any further here.  The processor will try to load a fixed amount of data, a cache line, from your container into the processor's data cache.  To help out the processor, you want your X and Y values close to each other.  Thus a container of Points will be more efficient than parallel containers.  With parallel containers, X[0] may not be in the same cache line as Y[0], causing the processor to reload the cache for Y.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thanks for your comments!! As for the first: the OO approach is "necessary", because several other classes will access the data and I want a clear and consistent representation of it. As for profiling... Yes, I know that you're right (keyword "premature optimization"... I'm prone to that... but I dared to ask because it's a quite fundamental design question here...) ---- as for all of your comments: Please copy them into an answer as I would like to accept it. You actually addressed my thoughts and the information you provided helps me to make a choice (and pick version 1). :-)